# Error showing when used fields in the mongoDB query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, ecmascript-6

I am trying to find specific filed in the MeteorJS MongoDB but it's not working. I am new to this environment.

```
const gallery = Gallery.find( 
    { userID: Meteor.userId() }, 
    { fields: { _id: 1, projectImage: 1, projectVideo: 0 } }, 
    { sort: { createdAt: -1 }, 
    limit: Session.get("eventLimit") } ).fetch({});
```

Comment: `{ fields: { _id: 1, projectImage: 1 },  sort: { .. }, limit: { } }`. Not in separate objects and don't mix `0` with `1`.  I did give you the relevant documentation link so you really should not have needed to ask this.

Comment: Please give more information about what exactly is "not working". For example, write an expected outcome and outcome that you got.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, first, "fields", "limit" and "sort" should all be in 1 "options" object and fetch does not require an argument, this example works:

```
const gallery = Gallery.find({
  userID: Meteor.userId()
},{ 
  fields: { _id: 1, projectImage: 1}, 
  sort: { createdAt: -1 }, 
  limit: Session.get("eventLimit") 
}).fetch();
```

also, please note that I removed "projectVideo:0" from my example, "it is not possible to mix inclusion and exclusion styles: the keys must either be all 1 or all 0. The exception is that you may specify _id: 0 in an inclusion specifier, which will leave _id out of the result object as well."
(from the Meteor docs [collections#fieldspecifiers](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#fieldspecifiers))

So you have to choose to whitelist your wanted fields with 1's or blacklist unwanted fields with 0.

Hope this helps!